# How to center the logo in the tcolorbox frame?

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    enhanced, breakable,
    colbacktitle=green, fonttitle=\large\bfseries, title=My title,
    subtitle style={empty, coltext=black},
    colback=white,
    boxrule=0.2mm, leftrule=1.7cm,
    drop lifted shadow=green!80!black,
    frame style={top color=green!80, bottom color=green!80, middle color=green!40},
    overlay={\bclampe},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm, yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={
        frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
            ([yshift=-1mm, xshift=-1mm] frame.north west) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm, xshift=1mm] frame.north east) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black, right color=tcbcolback!60!black, middle color=tcbcolback!80!black!75]
            ([xshift=-2mm] frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm] frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm] -- ([xshift=1mm, yshift=-1mm] frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- 
            ([xshift=-1mm, yshift=-1mm] frame.north west) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
        },
        interior engine=empty
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}
        My tcolorbox \\ My tcolorbox \\ My tcolorbox
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change `overlay={\bclampe}` to

```
overlay={
  \node[inner sep=0pt, xshift=.85cm, anchor=center] 
    at ($ (frame.north west)!.5!(frame.south west) $) {\bclampe};
}
```

where `xshift=.85cm` is half the value of `leftrule=1.7cm`.

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    enhanced, breakable,
    colbacktitle=green, fonttitle=\large\bfseries, title=My title,
    subtitle style={empty, coltext=black},
    colback=white,
    boxrule=0.2mm, leftrule=1.7cm,
    drop lifted shadow=green!80!black,
    frame style={top color=green!80, bottom color=green!80, middle color=green!40},
    overlay={
      \node[inner sep=0pt, xshift=.85cm, anchor=center] 
        at ($ (frame.north west)!.5!(frame.south west) $) {\bclampe};
    },
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm, yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={
        frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
            ([yshift=-1mm, xshift=-1mm] frame.north west) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm, xshift=1mm] frame.north east) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black, right color=tcbcolback!60!black, middle color=tcbcolback!80!black!75]
            ([xshift=-2mm] frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm] frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm] -- ([xshift=1mm, yshift=-1mm] frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- 
            ([xshift=-1mm, yshift=-1mm] frame.north west) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
        },
        interior engine=empty
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}
        My tcolorbox \\ My tcolorbox \\ My tcolorbox
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

To make the logo vertically centered in the height of "frame height - title height", you can change `overlay={...}` to

```
overlay={
  \node[inner sep=0pt, xshift=.85cm, anchor=center] 
    at ($ (frame.north west|-title.south)!.5!(frame.south west) $) {\bclampe};
}
```

Here `title` represents the bounding box of title in tcolorbox, a rectangular node. See the documentation of option `geometry nodes` in `tcolorbox`'s user manual.
[image]

Note that because of the part of left rule at the left of title, visually the logo is not centered well. A fraction less than `0.5` in `()!0.5!()`, for example `0.45`, might help.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question. If I want the vertical alignment to become without "My title"? And the inner sep is necessary? Sorry, two questions!

Comment: @FotisK I didn't get your point. Do you want to remove "My title" or something else? Maybe you can post a new question, with detailed description?

Comment: I want the logo to be stucked vertically in the center without calculating the title height.

Comment: @FotisK Currently, the height of title is not counted. So my answer already fits your requirement.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I said it wrong..the height of the title to be measured. Anyway, thank you for your time!

Comment: @FotisK Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful advice!